# How to check whether the file is last modified or not and only upload the modified file using Add-PnPFile from local to SharePoint using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-online, last-modified

i am trying to upload the files from my local to Sharepoint via Add-PnPFile.
But everytime i upload the file it overwrites the existing file.. and if the existing file is not modified also still it will upload it again.

I want to check wether the file is already there or not ? and if yes then i want to check the modified date whether it is being modified in last 1 day or not ?

*Any Suggestions to check and upload only the modified files ?*
**Code till Now** (i am missing the checking file thing i assume and dont know how to do it.)

```html
#install and import module
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 
#Get Connection to the url
Connect-PnPOnline "Some SharePoint Url" -UseWebLogin

#get the files from a local folder
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Some Local FolderPath" -Recurse

#Now check wether the file is being modified or not ? 
foreach($File in $Files){

    $LastWriteTimeForThisFile = $File.LastWriteTime.Day
    $difference = (Get-Date).Day - $LastWriteTimeForThisFile

        if ( $difference -lt 1) 
        {
        $upload = Add-PnPFile -Path $File.FullName -Folder $SharePointFolderPath
        #$message = "Successfully Uploaded" 
        Write-Host "======================Successfully Uploaded==============================="
        }
        else{
         Write-Host "=========Not Modified so not uploading again============"
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate your file name with the path uploaded to SharePoint, and use Get-PnPFile to check if the file exists. If the file exists, check the modification time of the file.

```
                try { 
                        $file=Get-PnPFile -Url "/sites/dev/Shared Documents/Facebook.png"-ErrorAction Stop
                        $file 
                        #do file exist action
                    }
                    catch {
                         Write-Host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -Foregroundcolor Red
                         #do file not exist action
                         
                         }
```